# Android json parsing this json response

Tags: android, json

I have this string of json

```
{"id":"8393933983"}
```

How do I parse this 
I'm trying like this to by using json object but its returning null pointer

My code

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject(response.getRawResponse);
String Id = object.getstring("id");
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: any code you have tried ?

Comment: Thats the code im using

Comment: here, `response` is of type `JSONResponse`. Right?

Comment: i can't find any issue in code. i think the issue is in the response.getRawresponse may be null

Comment: Replace the response.getRawResponse with "{\"id\":\"8393933983\"}" and try. if u don't get any issue then ur  response.getRawResponse is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {           
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"id\":\"8393933983\"}");
     String ID = jsonObject.optString("id");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```